# How to Perform Load test when When application is hosted on different servers(Webs Server, App server and Gateway Server)?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Application is hosted on different servers. 
Web Server
App Server 
GateWay Server.
I connect to application via client(RDP).)
I have to perform Load test and Performance Test.  On which Server I should install Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere. Or you will need to setup another "Server" which will be running only JMeter.

The reason is that when it comes to high loads both JMeter and your application will start struggling for OS resources (CPU, RAM, Network adapter, hard drive, etc.) so when you get high response times you won't be able to tell whether it is application bottleneck or just JMeter cannot send requests fast enough.

The main idea of well-behaved load test is that the test must represent real life application usage by real users so you can think of each JMeter thread (virtual user) as of the real user using the real browser with all the relevant stuff like [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), etc. So first of all I would recommend getting familiarized with [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article.

The chance that real users will access the application from the server where the application is running is close to zero so you need to determine where geographically the majority of users will be located and set up your JMeter instance (or instances in case of [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)) there